# Bring Value in account change

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help how to bring the value in 'On_Account' only in the first row where 'Account' changes.

Current result:

```
Account On_Account
10001   831278.44
10001   831278.44
10001   831278.44
10001   831278.44
10001   831278.44
10005   10000
10005   10000
10005   10000
10005   10000
10007   343434
10007   343434
10007   343434
10007   343434
10007   343434
10007   343434
10007   343434
10007   343434
```

Expected result:

```
Account On_Account
10001   831278.44
10001   
10001   
10001   
10001   
10005   10000
10005   
10005   
10005   
10007   343434
10007   
10007   
10007   
10007   
10007   
10007   
10007
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   Account    INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,On_Account NUMERIC(9,2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO test
(Account,On_Account) VALUES 
(10001,831278.44),
(10001,831278.44),
(10001,831278.44),
(10001,831278.44),
(10001,831278.44),
(10005,10000),
(10005,10000),
(10005,10000),
(10005,10000),
(10007,343434),
(10007,343434),
(10007,343434),
(10007,343434),
(10007,343434),
(10007,343434),
(10007,343434),
(10007,343434);
```

use `Row_number` to distinguish the first value and use `Subquery` to filter  first value with using `IIF` function.

if you want show data as `null` use first IIF and if you want show data as `'  '` use second IIF and comment the first

```
select Account
,iif( rn=1,On_Account ,null) On_Account 
--,iif( rn=1,cast(On_Account as varchar(100)) ,'  ') On_Account 
from(
select Account,On_Account, Row_number()
                 OVER(   PARTITION BY Account
                   ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
                   from test) T
```

[`Dbfiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec7747303cec578a6c24f93a97955182)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.  If the test is primary table,I am getting the result. in my case table test left joined with another table, how will I achieve same result